# Django url добавление .html

Tags: python, django

Как сделать так чтобы в конце `url` добавлялось `.html`?

```
url(r'^blog/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)\.html$', "apps.common.views.blog_detail", name="blog_detail"),
```

Так не работает

Comment: Вопрос - зачем? Они отлично смотрятся без `.html`.

Comment: типв такого blog\blog.key\blog.title_url.html, заче? так сказали я делаю

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Вы хотите, чтобы нормальные url редиректили на `.html`? Или чтобы доступ был только по `.html`, по остальным - 404?

Comment: чтобы нормальные url редиректили на .html

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При редиректе всех запросов любые готовые приложения откажутся работать.

Проверку на адекватность редиректа все-таки стоит сделать через попытку resolve нового url

`project/middleware.py`

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class HtmlRedirectMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.path.endswith('.html'):
            new_path = request.path + '.html'
            try:
                resolve(new_path)
            except Resolver404:
                pass
            else:
                return redirect(new_path)
```

`project/settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'project.middleware.HtmlRedirectMiddleware',
    # ...
)
```

либо банально по списку regexp, вынесенному в настройки

`project/middleware.py`

```
import re
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings

class HtmlRedirectMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.path.endswith('.html'):
            new_path = request.path + '.html'
            if not any(re.search(regexp, request.path) for regexp in settings.HTML_REDIRECT_EXCLUDE):
                return redirect(new_path)
```

`project/settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'project.middleware.HtmlRedirectMiddleware',
    # ...
)
HTML_REDIRECT_EXCLUDE = (
    r'^/admin/',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно, чтобы все-все урлы редиректили на .html, добавьте middleware https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#process-request и напишите в process_request что-то типа

```
if not request.path.endswith('.html'):
    return redirect(request.path + '.html')
```

в urls.py все оставьте как в примере (c .html на конце)