# Добавление префикса к url которые формирует django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

Есть middleware который проверяет url на наличие префикса в адресе и редиректит, при его отсутствии, на адрес с префиксом. При этом заменяя значения в request так чтобы казалось что этого префикса нету. Всё работает хорошо, за исключением того что новые url генерируются без этого префикса, что приводит к избыточному редиректу.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ глобально переопределить методы для формирования url'ов, чтобы они формировались с нужным мне префиксом? Т.е. есть модель, которая зарегистрирована для редактирование в django админке, необходимо чтобы url'ы, которые генерирует сам django были сразу с префиксами.

P.S. Префикс стоит перед сигнатурой языка, для этого и необходимо прикидываться.

P.S.S. Модели могут быть не моего приложения и доступа к их коду у меня нету.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы хотите что-то вроде этого:

```
# urls.py
from .views import PrefixUrlRedirect
old_urlpatterns = patterns('',
    * * *
    url(r'^some_view/$', some_view),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^prefix', include(old_urlpatterns)),
    url(r'^(\S+)', PrefixUrlRedirect.as_view())
)


# views.py
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.shortcuts import Http404

class PrefixUrlRedirect(RedirectView):
    query_string = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url_without_prefix = self.args[0]
        if not url_without_prefix.find("prefix") + 1:
            url = "".join(["/", "prefix", url_without_prefix])
            return url
        else:
            # В случае, если url с префиксом не существует, вернём 404
            raise Http404
```

При переходе на some_view/ перенаправит на prefixsome_view/

На prefixsome_view/ передаст управление в some_view

Обратите внимание: **обязателен слеш в конце каждого URL**

**UPD** Если очень хочется, можно посмотреть [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430524/django-url-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-html?rq=1), и переделать в виде мидлвари. Но смысла в этом не много.

**UPD2** Вопрос изменился, отвечаю на его вторую часть.
Тут по сути два варианта:

1) Создать templatetag со своим формированием URL Смотрим как устроен штатный URL, смотрим как устроен reverse и вперёд

2) Генерировать URL в ручную

выбор за вами.

**UPD3** Напишу подробнее:

Создаём template_tag:
    # templatetags/my_templatetags.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag 
def my_url(url_name, prefix):
    return prefix+reverse(url_name)
```

В шаблоне подключаем файл с тегом через:

```
{% load my_templatetags %}
```

Вызываем там, где нужен URL:

```
{% my_url "url-name" "prefix" %}
```

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при этом сохранялась информация о локале. т.е. было ru-ru/, en-ru/ и т.д. ru- и en- в данном случае префикс.

Comment: а это уже можно сделать через middleware: 
просто проверяем request.path на предмет наличия префикса:
if request.path.find("en-en") + 1:  kwargs["locale"] = EN
(это на вскидку, в коде не проверял, но думаю логика понятна)

Comment: тьфу ты... просто добавляем локальную переменную:
url(r'^en-en', include(old_urlpatterns) {'locale': 'en'} ),

Comment: к сожалению не так все просто - язык он берёт не из kwars ;-( но спасибо, попробую пойти этим путём. Хотя проблема в том что стандартные ссылки генерировались  в виде ru-ru/ а не ru/

Comment: ничего не понял. Поподробнее. Кто берёт? Куда? locale я чисто для примера привёл, можно хоть куда записать это значение.

Comment: Идея в том, чтобы джанго и джанго цмс вели себя как-будто никакого префикса и нету. Но при этом не происходило лишнего редиректа, т.е. открыли страницу с prefix-locale/... и все ссылки джанговские были тоже с prefix-locale/... а не с locale/... Проблема в том что не в своём коде ссылки были с префиксом, а вообще в системе.

Comment: Никаких лишних редиректов там нет. При смене URL редирект необходим.

Comment: Так мы открыли страницу в админке джанго смс. по урлу с префиксом и выставлением языка. Он генерит ссылки на странице без префикса. при переходе оно редиректится на префикс. Хочется чтобы сразу генерил с префиксом. и  `url(r'^prefix', include(old_urlpatterns)),` не сделать если old_urlpatterns включает в себя i18n_pattern

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация вообще зло, а если в админке - тем-более глупо что-либо оптимизировать. там полтора человека максимальная нагрузка обычно.

Comment: Тут дело зло это или нет. Тут дело в том что это надо.

Comment: написал вам templatetag смотрите в дополнении к ответу

Comment: Так проблема то в том что мне не СВОИ (прикладные url) надо правильно генерировать, их то понятно как, а URL django и django CMS админки менять надо.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30477/discussion-between--and--).

Comment: А что мешает? Просто нужно переопределить шаблоны админки и CMS. Копируете нужные в свою папку template и меняете теги

Comment: Вот, даже ссылку скину: http://djbook.ru/ch17s02.html

Answer (score 4):

Если в корневом `urls.py` проекта была конструкция вида

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
)
```

, то можно заменить на

```
old_urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^prefix/', include(old_urlpatterns)),
)
```

Comment: А толку то? В итоге то урл будет вида `mysite.com/[lang-prefix]/[prefix]/...` а надо чтобы был `mysite.com/[prefix][lang-prefix]/...`

Comment: @Чад А как устроена интернационализация? У меня для этого служат `i18n_patterns` вместо `patterns`, и с ними этот фокус вполне должен сработать: инклудим в `patterns` с префиксом `i18n_patterns` -- получаем префиксы в нужном порядке.

Comment: К сожалению получаем ошибку `ImproperlyConfigured: Using i18n_patterns in an included URLconf is not allowed.` А так бы было бы красиво. Беда в том что это не просто префикс, а язык. Для того чтобы он работал, ещё добавлена мидлеваря которая меняет меты путей выленяя из них префикс. А вот как заставить формировать урл не нашёл :-(