# Как запустить сайт на Django в подпути?

Tags: python, django

Появилась задача запустить сайт на Django не на всём домене, а внутри подпути, то есть чтобы по адресу типа `http://example.com/subpath/` открывалась главная, по адресу `http://example.com/subpath/admin/` админка и так далее. Как это сделать, не переписывая вручную абсолютно все ссылки в urls.py? Иначе говоря, как добавить префикс ко всем URL в Django?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452905 (но там более частный случай с локализацией и редиректами)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для случая, когда перед Django стоит nginx *(а именно так и должно быть на продакшене)* [enSO предлагает](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147916) прописать [FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#force-script-name) в settings.py (или ином DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE):

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/subpath'
```

Тогда настройка nginx может выглядеть примерно так:

```
server_name example.com;
# ...
location /subpath/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;  # внимание: есть слэш в конце
    include proxy_params;
    # ...
}
```

В таком случае запросы на nginx будут поступать в виде `http://example.com/subpath/admin/` и перенаправляться в Django в виде `http://localhost:8000/admin/`. В ответе Django будет приписывать `/subpath` ко всем ссылкам на странице (при использовании `reverse` или `{% url %}`, разумеется).

---

Эта настройка может быть неудобна тем, что Django принимает ссылки строго без `/subpath`, что не очень удобно при разработке. Поэтому я предпочитаю прописывать префикс в urls.py явно. Это можно сделать ровно один раз в root urlconf:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
# ... прочие импорты

urlpatterns = [url(settings.URL_PREFIX, include([
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ... и так далее
]))]
```

И, соответственно, прописываем в settings.py:

```
URL_PREFIX = 'subpath/'
```

Чтобы префикс не использовался, пишем `URL_PREFIX = ''`.

Тогда настройка nginx будет немного отличаться:

```
server_name example.com;
# ...
location /subpath/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;  # внимание: слэш в конце пропал
    include proxy_params;
    # ...
}
```

Таким образом Django принимает запросы вида `http://localhost:8000/subpath/admin/`, и это нормально работает на dev-сервере совсем без nginx, что удобно для тестирования.

Ну и ещё `STATIC_ROOT = '/subpath/static/'` и `MEDIA_ROOT = '/subpath/media/'` по вкусу.

---

Про влияние слэша и других URI в конце proxy_pass читайте в [документации nginx](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

(И не забывайте, что ни в коем случае нельзя запускать встроенный dev-сервер Django на продакшене, потому что он небезопасен. Используйте uwsgi, gunicorn или другие серьёзные wsgi-серверы.)